# iOS: not working segue dimensions

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, transition, segue

The segue should perform animation where new controller slides from right to centre of screen, while the old controller simultaneously slides from centre to left.

I input all the dimensions that should be logically correct, but the segue performs a very different movement.

Instead of desired animation, new controller appears immediately on the centre and then slides to the right of the screen.

This is my code:

```
UIViewController* src;
UIViewController* dst;

- (void)perform
{
    src = (UIViewController *)self.sourceViewController;
    dst = (UIViewController *)self.destinationViewController;



    float width = src.view.bounds.size.width;
    float height = src.view.bounds.size.height;

    dst.view.bounds = CGRectMake(width, 0, width, height);


    [src.view addSubview:dst.view];


    [UIView animateWithDuration:5 animations:^{

        dst.view.bounds = CGRectMake(width, 0, width, height);
        src.view.bounds = CGRectMake(-width, 0, width, height);

    }];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(present) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}

- (void)present
{
    [[self sourceViewController] presentViewController:[self destinationViewController] animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change:

```
   dst.view.bounds = CGRectMake(width, 0, width, height);
```

to:

```
dst.view.frame = CGRectMake(-width, 0, width, height);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have two problems with this though. 

Firstly, I quite don't understand how first setting x coordinate to -width and then moving it to -width again would make it move anywhere.

Secondly, I need it to swipe from right to left, not from left to right, and I'm not really sure which dimensions should I change to which because none keep working out for me.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried it?
cause for me it's working - I built a new project with it. 
It is being swiped from left to right. 

You need to pat attention for the frame and the found - this is the trick :)

Comment: Tell me if something is not clear I will try to help you - 
It's a nice idea

Comment: Thanks again. It work's perfectly, its just that, as you said, its swiping from left to right, not from right to left. Its just a minor tweek that I don't know how to accomplish.

Comment: I just made it. I changed all the lines which contained `-width` to `width` (I deleted minus). It works but I'm still not sure why. It  would be logical for me that in the `animateWithDuration` block, the destinationViewController would move to ` = 0`, while the source would move to `-width`, instead, all move to `width`. Do you know how this works?